# "Ambiguous reference to member 'subscript'"

Tags: swift

I've just had several `Ambiguous reference to member 'subscript'` errors that weren't solved by existing answers. This code illustrates the problem:

```
enum Keys: String {
    case items = "items"
    // …
}

if let parseJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [String:Any],
    let items = parseJSON[Keys.items] as? [[String:Any]]
{
    // …
}
```

Producing the error on `parseJSON[Keys.items]`.

Comment: No need to set exactly the same string representation to your cases

Comment: @LeoDabus Thanks. As it happens, not all the enum cases had values equal to their names, I just stripped out most of the enum cases to make it more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `Keys.items` is of type `Keys`, not of type `String`. The solution is to index with `Keys.items.rawValue` instead of `Keys.items`.